# Print Error Message in same window using Swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to display error message "Mandatory field not filled correctly" in the same window in the red rectangle area when mandatory field Decision Forum is selected and pressed Ok without selecting valid value from drop-down list of Responsible Forum.

[image: See This link for Reference]

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"I want to.."* OK Go for it. What's the problem?

Comment: you can use primary hidden lables and while validating rules if you found any error then just show lables with desired formatting.

Comment: Why do you need to show it in the same window? Would a popup be sufficient as well? Also you could set the font color of the label with the missing information to red. And would it be an option, to set a default to your dropdown?

Comment: First try to do research little bit and start implementation. When you have problems with the code we will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden label and set it visible inside the catch of the error.